# Assign height of one div to another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make two divs with the same height.

```
<div id="grey"></div>
<div id="pink"></div>

#grey{
    background-color: grey;
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#pink{
    background-color: pink;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

var g = $( '#grey' ).height();
var p = $( '#pink' ).height();
g = p;
```

alert(g) - shows me that the #grey have height 500 but in browser both divs has different sizes. What wrong, and how can I made this two divs whith same heigh?

Comment: `g = p` ? what do you think it will do ?

Comment: Why you  need to have divs with the same height?

Comment: Did you want `$( '#grey' ).height($( '#pink' ).height());` ?

Comment: @dystroy think it will assign the height of grey to pink, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong, you assign the height of pink to *the variable g*, not to the height of g. When you do `g = $( '#grey' ).height();` you take the *result* of a function call and you copy that value into the variable g. You don't create a permanent link between g and how it was filled.

Comment: @dystroy, tnx for usefull info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `g=p`, that's like writing `$( '#grey' ).height() = $( '#pink' ).height()` which makes no sense, and instead use:

```
$( '#grey' ).height(p);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3FVV5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your CSS you are defining height of gray div as height: 300px; and blue height: 500px;

```
var g = $( '#grey' ).height();
var p = $( '#pink' ).height();
g = p;
```

in the last line your are  assigning the value of p to g. Since the value of pink is 500px therefore after this assignment g will be 500px. therefore its showing as 500px;

To make the same height keep the same height attribute in css file